# Why is my Time Machine backup trying to backup everything from scratch?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, user-accounts, time-machine, file-permissions, time-capsule

I have a MacBook Pro from work, and I backup a single 20GB folder on it called "Projects" that sits within the root directory on the main hard drive. Recently, our IT department had to create us all new user accounts (I won't go into the reasons here), but the my new user account has the same name as my old one, which has been renamed.

Since bringing the laptop back home, it's been trying to backup the machine again, but for some reason it's trying to do the whole thing from scratch even though the only folder being backed up isn't even in my user folder. This is what Console.app outputs:

```
Failed to resolve network service using name = xxx type = _afpovertcp._tcp domain = local.
Attempting to mount network destination using URL: afp://xxx@xxx._afpovertcp._tcp.local/Backups
NetAuthConnectToServerSync failed with error: 64 for url: afp://xxx@xxx._afpovertcp._tcp.local/Backups
Failed to resolve network service using name = xxx type = _afpovertcp._tcp domain = local.
Backup failed with error: 19
Starting standard backup
Attempting to mount network destination using URL: afp://xxx@xxx._afpovertcp._tcp.local/Backups
Mounted network destination using URL: afp://xxx@xxx._afpovertcp._tcp.local/Backups
QUICKCHECK ONLY; FILESYSTEM CLEAN
Disk image /Volumes/Backups-1/LAP-MPB2.sparsebundle mounted at: /Volumes/Time Machine Backups
Backing up to: /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb
```

There is one change to the projects folder I had to make... I had to add my new user account's file permissions to "read/write" for all the files in the Projects folder. Does this mean it has to backup every individual file again just because the permissions have changed?

By the way I am on Snow Leopard and it is backing up wirelessly to a Time Capsule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The way fseventsd works could mean it can't tell the files are the same.

You can always delete the older version of that folder if you want to free space, but it may or may not flatten the files at the end of the backup. You have to let it finish to know for sure. The best you can do is wire an ethernet cable and exclude some large folders to let it do the new backup in chunks if you can't let it sit to move all the data again.